# How to observe property with flow in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a functional property:

```kotlin
  var callback: ((value: Int) -> unit)? = null
```

Then, I want to wrap this callback with flow, when callback is invoked, flow will emit the value passed.

First, I tried this:

```kotlin
  fun toFlow() = flow {
    // save origin callback
    val tempCallback = callback
    callback = { value ->
      // invoke origin callback
      tempCallback.invoke(value)
      emit(value)
    }
  }
```

However, emit need called in suspend function, So I need to assign callback function to suspend function like this:

```kotlin
 fun toFlow() = flow {
    val tempCallback = callback
    callback = suspend { value ->
      tempCallback.invoke(value)
      emit(value)
    }
  }
```

But suspend function is not equal with normal function, so callback can not assigned to suspend function.

So is there a way to make it?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? I'm not sure because it seems so unusual and I can't think of a use case. But you want `toFlow()` to immediately replace whatever is stored in `callback` with a wrapped version of itself that also emits its input values to the Flow returned by `toFlow()`? Can you give any example of how it's meant to be used?

Comment: It's also fragile because every time `collect` or other terminal operator is called on the return Flow, it will call this block again, which will re-wrap whatever is currently set in the property. If the `callback` property is changed, currently collecting versions of the Flow will no longer publish anything and `collect` will have to be called on them again to start listening to the new function.

Comment: @Tenfour04  Thanks for your reply. I just want that flow can emit the callback argument. I thought using delegate first, but I don't know how to do this; then i thought I can wrap callback, however this way is not feasible either. And I know the shortage. I will use sharedflow instead, and use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

[callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) may suit your needs.

```kotlin
class MyClass(var callback: ((value: Int) -> Unit)? = null) {
    private lateinit var invoker: (x: Int) -> Unit

    fun toFlow() = callbackFlow {
        invoker = {
            callback?.invoke(it)
            trySend(it)
        }
        awaitClose {}
    }

    fun invoke(x: Int) {
        invoker.invoke(x)
    }
}

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    val myClass = MyClass { println("From callback: $it") }

    myClass
        .toFlow()
        .onEach { println("From flow: $it") }
        .launchIn(this)

    delay(1_000)
    myClass.invoke(1)
    myClass.invoke(2)
}
```

###### Output

```
From callback: 1
From callback: 2
From flow: 1
From flow: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is here. Why do you need both a callback and a Flow?

If what you need is to expose a non-suspend function that then emits a value on a Flow, that isn't really possible without buffering. Flows work by suspending during emission until its subscribers have consumed that event.

If you are ok with buffering (and potentially dropping events), you can achieve something close with a Channel.

```kotlin
val channel = Channel<Int>(capacity = 10) // buffering up to 10 events

val invokingFlow = channel.consumeAsFlow()

val invoker: (Int) -> Unit = { channel.trySend(it) }

invokingFlow
    .toFlow()
    .onEach { print(it) }
    .launchIn(this)

invoker(10)
```